# Increasing order of charge/mass ratio for electron, proton, alpha-particle and neutron

Tags: electrons, charge

So there is this question where we have to arrange the charge by mass ratio of the aforementioned particles/ions.
So I googled for the answer and in most of the places the answer is given as:

n < α < p < e

which only makes sense if you consider the charge of the electron to be the same as that of proton (in sign and in magnitude). I don't see why we have to do that. I mean I was taught that ratios are always positive in primary school but I don't think that definition would extend here.

Comment: Although charge can be either positive or negative, when we are considering charge is to mass ratio, it essentially means "the amount of charge concentrated by the body per unit mass" so, there is no notion that whether those charge is negative or positive.

Comment: @PhysicsLover thanks for answering.

Comment: Your most Welcome :)

Comment: @PhysicsLover that commet should instead be posted as an answer instead.

Comment: ok, sorry... New here, so getting little familiar with this.

Comment: @mathenjoyer It's comparison of charge density magnitude without sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although charge can be either positive or negative, when we are considering charge is to mass ratio, it essentially means "the amount of charge concentrated by the body per unit mass" so, there is no notion that whether those charge is negative or positive